# How to filter Livedata or Rxjava flowable

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, android-livedata

Using retrofit I am fetching Flowable data from server, then in viewmodel i am converting the flowable to Livedata and finally observing the LiveData in activity. Inside activity I am using the Livedata for my recyclerView.

But I need to filter the Data with some condition and get the filtered Data list as LiveData. How and where do I do it? Can i filter Livedata?

The steps I am doing are:

1. In my  **MainApi class** : Calling webservice using retrofit which return Flowable result

```
public interface MainApi {
    @GET("xx")
    Flowable<List<User>> getUsers();
}
```

2. In my **Respository class**:

```
public class MainRepository {
    public Flowable<List<User>> fetchUsersFromServer() {   
        Flowable<List<User>> returnedData = mainApi
            .getUsers()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

        return returnedData;
    }   
}
```

3. In my **viewModel class**: get flowable from Repository and convert to LiveData

```
public class MainViewModel extends ViewModel {
    MediatorLiveData<List<User>> liveUsers = new MediatorLiveData();

    public void getUsersFromServer() {

    final LiveData<List<User>> source = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher( mainRepository.fetchUsersFromServer());

    liveUsers.addSource(source, new Observer<List<User>>() {
          @Override
          public void onChanged(List<User> users) {
              liveUsers.setValue(users);
              liveUsers.removeSource(source);
          }
        });     
    }
}
```

4. Finally observing the LiveData from **Activity** and showing data in Recyclerview

Answer (score 0):

You can do the filtering in the observable you are returning from `mainRepository.fetchUsersFromServer()` before you convert it into a LiveData.

```
public void getUsersFromServer() {
        Flowable<List<User>> usersObservable = mainRepository.fetchUsersFromServer()
                .filter(new Predicate<List<User>>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean test(List<User> users) throws Exception {
                        return !users.isEmpty(); // put your filter condition
                    }
                });
        final LiveData<List<User>> source = LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(usersObservable);
        liveUsers.addSource(source, new Observer<List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<User> users) {
                liveUsers.setValue(users);
                liveUsers.removeSource(source);
            }
        });
    }
```